# Excel count of number of times a unique value has been selected

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, duplicate, countif

I have a long file with three columns, the first column contains the name of institutions, the second column contains the name of customers within each institutions and the third columns contains a Yes/No field to indicate if a specific customer within a specific institution has been selected

```
Inst.   Cust.   Selected
INST_1  CUST_1  Yes
INST_1  CUST_2  Yes
INST_1  CUST_3  
INST_1  CUST_4  
INST_2  CUST_5  Yes
INST_2  CUST_6  
INST_2  CUST_7  
INST_3  CUST_8  Yes
INST_3  CUST_9  
INST_3  CUST_10 
INST_3  CUST_11 
INST_3  CUST_12 Yes
INST_3  CUST_13 
INST_3  CUST_14 
INST_4  CUST_15 
INST_4  CUST_16 Yes
INST_4  CUST_17 Yes
INST_4  CUST_18 Yes
```

I am interested in calculating the number of institutions in which one, two or more than two customers have been selected.

I am familiar with solutions using pivot tables but in my case case it would be more practical to have the result generated by a formula. In the example the desired output is:

> number of institutions with one selected customer: 1
>
> number of institutions with two selected customers: 2
>
> number of institutions with three or more selected customer: 1

Comment: Is the data sorted as shown so solutions can rely on the institution records to be contiguous?  If so, and you don't want to use a pivot table, you could use a helper column to populate either the 1st or last row for each institution with a count of Yes's for the institution.  Then COUNTIF the count values for the various results you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the marco coding function in VBA plugin.  I won't give the exact code because it changes every so often.  But here is some basic pseudo coding.

1. "GET" the data from the cell to look first.  Once you figure how your excel get data, figure how to loop this.
2. Set up the formula for analysis then "PUT" into a data cell
3. Advance to the next cell or increment it to the next cell.
   note:  Instead of GET and PUT, you could use the READ and WRITE.  I believe the difference between the two is one read the binary value and the other the string values.  Most programmers use string values to store values and they process it into a float or an int.

Answer (score 0):

I spent more time and the problem and I found a solution leveraging the approach illustrated in the post [Count unique numeric values with criteria](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-numeric-values-with-criteria)

To implement the formula I added an additional column transforming the Inst. column into a column containing only numerical IDs. This is necessary to be able to use the `FREQUENCY` function.

```
Inst.   Inst_ID Cust.   Selected
INST_1     1    CUST_1  Yes
INST_1     1    CUST_2  Yes
INST_1     1    CUST_3  
INST_1     1    CUST_4  
INST_2     2    CUST_5  Yes
INST_2     2    CUST_6  
INST_2     2    CUST_7  
INST_3     3    CUST_8  Yes
INST_3     3    CUST_9  
INST_3     3    CUST_10 
INST_3     3    CUST_11 
INST_3     3    CUST_12 Yes
INST_3     3    CUST_13 
INST_3     3    CUST_14 
INST_4     4    CUST_15 
INST_4     4    CUST_16 Yes
INST_4     4    CUST_17 Yes
INST_4     4    CUST_18 Yes
```

The number of institutions which have been selected only once can now be calculated as `SUM(1*(FREQUENCY(IF(Selected="Yes",Inst_ID),Inst_ID)=1))`. Cases where the institutions have been selected twice or more can be calculated in a similar way.

The bin array in the `FREQUENCY` function cal also be pointed to a list of the unique Inst_ID.